# Dopants vs impurities

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, crystals

The question is related to terminology. What is the difference between dopants and impurities in condensed matter (semiconductor) physics?

Comment: The difference is psychological: the word "impurity" is used for defects or imperfections, which are unwanted. People realised that impurities can be good, so they chose to use the word "dopant" in those cases instead.

Comment: Or, more specifically, dopant atoms have energy levels in the semiconductor band gap close enough to the band edges to either donate an electron to the conduction band or donate a hole to the valence band. A decent semiconductor physics book like Sze will show a graph for, e.g. Silicon, with lots of impurities and where their energy levels are. It turns out that there really aren't many options for good dopants.